# Misconfiguration after importing hebrew language in polyglossia (XeLaTeX)

Tags: xetex, polyglossia, hebrew

I am making a work that's mainly written in portuguese but has some biblical hebrew words and phrases. I am using ABNTeX2 and XeLaTeX (this issue does not happens when compiling with LuaLaTeX), but everytime I load hebrew language with `\setotherlanguage{hebrew}`, the sections numeration goes mental and the abstract title fonts change.

```latex
\documentclass[
    article,
    12pt,
    oneside,
    a4paper,
    ]{abntex2}

% Pacotes fundamentais 
\usepackage{indentfirst}        % Indenta o primeiro parágrafo de cada seção.
\usepackage{nomencl}            % Lista de simbolos
\usepackage{color}              % Controle das cores
\usepackage{graphicx}           % Inclusão de gráficos
\usepackage{microtype}          % para melhorias de justificação
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

% Usar Arial conforme manual do UNASP
\setmainfont{Arial}

% Pacotes adicionais, usados apenas no âmbito do Modelo Canônico do abnteX2
\usepackage{lipsum}             % para geração de dummy text
        
% Pacotes de citações
\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}   % Citações padrão ABNT

% Define tamanho de títulos e subtítuos
\renewcommand{\ABNTEXsectionfont}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\ABNTEXsectionfontsize}{\normalsize}

\renewcommand{\ABNTEXsubsectionfont}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\ABNTEXsubsectionfontsize}{\normalsize}

\renewcommand{\ABNTEXsubsubsectionfont}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\ABNTEXsubsubsubsectionfont}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont}

\setsecnumformat{\csname the#1\endcsname\space} % Define espaçamento entre número e título de seção como sendo um espaço único

% Define o espaçamento entre títulos e subtítulos e texto
\setbeforesecskip{2\onelineskip}
\setaftersecskip{2\onelineskip}
\setbeforesubsecskip{2\onelineskip}
\setaftersubsecskip{2\onelineskip}
\setbeforesubsubsecskip{2\onelineskip}
\setaftersubsubsecskip{2\onelineskip}

% Definir estilos para paginação
\aliaspagestyle{plain}{empty}
\makeevenhead{simple}{\footnotesize\thepage}{}{}
\makeoddhead{simple}{}{}{\footnotesize\thepage}

% Redefinir citação para usar tamanho UNASP
\let\oldCitacao\citacao
\let\oldEndCitacao\endcitacao

\renewenvironment{citacao}
    {
    \oldCitacao
    \small
    }
    {\oldEndCitacao}
    
% Configuração do pacote polyglossia
\setdefaultlanguage{brazil}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}

% Informações de dados para CAPA e FOLHA DE ROSTO
\titulo{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
\tituloestrangeiro{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}

\autor{
Lorem ipsum\thanks{\lipsum[1] E-mail: \mbox{\href{mailto:lorem@ipsum.com}{lorem@ipsum.com}.}}}

\local{Brasil}
\data{2022}

% Configurações de aparência do PDF final
\makeatletter
\hypersetup{
        pagebackref=true,
    pdftitle={\@title}, 
    pdfauthor={\@author},
        pdfsubject={Modelo de artigo científico com abnTeX2},
    pdfcreator={LaTeX with abnTeX2},
    pdfkeywords={abnt}{latex}{abntex}{abntex2}{atigo científico}, 
    colorlinks=true,            % false: boxed links; true: colored links
        linkcolor=black,            % color of internal links
        citecolor=black,                % color of links to bibliography
        filecolor=black,            % color of file links
    urlcolor=black,
    bookmarksdepth=4
}
\makeatother

% Altera as margens padrões
\setlrmarginsandblock{3cm}{2cm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{3cm}{2cm}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout

% O tamanho do parágrafo é dado por:
\setlength{\parindent}{1.25cm}

% Controle do espaçamento entre um parágrafo e outro:
\setlength{\parskip}{0cm} 

\DoubleSpacing

% Espaçamento entre notas de rodapé e texto
\setlength{\skip\footins}{\baselineskip}

% ----
% Início do documento
% ----
\begin{document}

% Retira espaço extra obsoleto entre as frases.
\frenchspacing 

% ----------------------------------------------------------
% ELEMENTOS PRÉ-TEXTUAIS
% ----------------------------------------------------------

% página de titulo principal (obrigatório)
\maketitle

% titulo em outro idioma (opcional)

% resumo em português
\begin{resumoumacoluna}
\lipsum[1]
 
 \vspace{\onelineskip}
 
 \noindent
 \textbf{Palavras-chave}: lorem. ipsum. dolor.
\end{resumoumacoluna}

% resumo em inglês
\renewcommand{\resumoname}{Abstract}
\begin{resumoumacoluna}
 \begin{otherlanguage*}{english}
   \lipsum[1]

   \vspace{\onelineskip}
 
   \noindent
   \textbf{Keywords}: lorem. ipsum. dolor.
 \end{otherlanguage*}  
\end{resumoumacoluna}

% ----------------------------------------------------------
% ELEMENTOS TEXTUAIS
% ----------------------------------------------------------
\textual
\pagestyle{simple}

% ----------------------------------------------------------
% Introdução
% ----------------------------------------------------------
\section{Introdução}

\lipsum[3]

\section{Lorem ipsum}

\lipsum[6]


% Finaliza a parte no bookmark do PDF, para que se inicie o bookmark na raiz
\bookmarksetup{startatroot}% 

% ---
% Conclusão
% ---
\section{Considerações finais}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{citacao}

\lipsum[2]

\end{citacao}

\lipsum[3]

% ----------------------------------------------------------
% ELEMENTOS PÓS-TEXTUAIS
% ----------------------------------------------------------
\postextual

% ----------------------------------------------------------
% Referências bibliográficas
% ----------------------------------------------------------
\bibliography{Artigo}

\end{document}
```

I also made an Overleaf project. Uncommenting the line 66 will reproduce the problem.

https://www.overleaf.com/8472821766fcfkjtzpktjw

I've tried for hours to find a solution online and reading the polyglossia manual, but didn't manage to solve this problem. THe problem also does not happen when adding other languages that I am going to use, like English.

**With hebrew language disabled:**
[image]

**With hebrew language enabled:**
[image]

Note the differences on the **Abstract** title and on the section numeration.

Comment: Please add here the minimal example, not as a link to Overleaf.

Comment: please make an example as a code block here not an external link. That link is not world readable, and even if it was, if the code there changes this question would not be understandable.

Comment: hebrew loads the bidi package, and the bidi package changes lots of things. If you adapt e.g. counters and similar, better do if *after* hebrew has been load, so that you have a fighting chance that your changes win.

Comment: Sorry, I included the source in the question too.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yeah, I though this could be the case, but I've tried moving the set language command to both before and after all other configurations, but this didn't change anything.

Comment: Confirmed that this does not happen with LuaLaTeX.

Comment: `abntex2` itself already loads `babel`. So perhaps instead of using `polyglossia` and `\setdefaultlanguage` `\setotherlanguage`, you can get `babel` to work with English and Hebrew with `\babelprovide{english}\babelprovide{hebrew}`? This seems to leave the style settings intact.

Comment: @imnothere I may try it. I am intrigued about why the problem does not happens with LuaLaTeX, tho.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding imnothere's comment into an answer, and removing the extraneous material:

```
\documentclass[
    article,
    12pt,
    oneside,
    a4paper,
    ]{abntex2}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\babelprovide{english}
\babelprovide{hebrew}

% Usar Arial conforme manual do UNASP
\setmainfont{Arial}

% Pacotes adicionais, usados apenas no âmbito do Modelo Canônico do abnteX2
\usepackage{lipsum}             % para geração de dummy text
        
% Pacotes de citações
\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}   % Citações padrão ABNT

% Define tamanho de títulos e subtítuos
\renewcommand{\ABNTEXsectionfont}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\ABNTEXsectionfontsize}{\normalsize}

\renewcommand{\ABNTEXsubsectionfont}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\ABNTEXsubsectionfontsize}{\normalsize}

\renewcommand{\ABNTEXsubsubsectionfont}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\ABNTEXsubsubsubsectionfont}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont}


% Informações de dados para CAPA e FOLHA DE ROSTO
\titulo{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
\tituloestrangeiro{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}

\autor{
Lorem ipsum\thanks{\lipsum[1] E-mail: \mbox{\href{mailto:lorem@ipsum.com}{lorem@ipsum.com}.}}}

\local{Brasil}
\data{2022}


\begin{document}


% ----------------------------------------------------------
% ELEMENTOS PRÉ-TEXTUAIS
% ----------------------------------------------------------

% página de titulo principal (obrigatório)
\maketitle

% titulo em outro idioma (opcional)

% resumo em português
\begin{resumoumacoluna}
\lipsum[1]
 
 \vspace{\onelineskip}
 
 \noindent
 \textbf{Palavras-chave}: lorem. ipsum. dolor.
\end{resumoumacoluna}

% resumo em inglês
\renewcommand{\resumoname}{Abstract}
\begin{resumoumacoluna}
 \begin{otherlanguage*}{english}
   \lipsum[1]

   \vspace{\onelineskip}
 
   \noindent
   \textbf{Keywords}: lorem. ipsum. dolor.
 \end{otherlanguage*}  
\end{resumoumacoluna}

% ----------------------------------------------------------
% ELEMENTOS TEXTUAIS
% ----------------------------------------------------------
\textual
% ----------------------------------------------------------
\section{Introdução - שלום }

שלום 

\lipsum[3]

\section{Lorem ipsum}

\lipsum[6]


\end{document}
```